# MS Teams call event

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

we have a windows form made using VB.net

Is there an API we can use, so that when a call is received in Teams an event is triggered?

And in the event it can determine the caller number?

And is there an event for when the call is finished, which can determine how long the call lasted?

Thanks

Comment: There is no direct why that you can handle the call triggered event at your custom application but you can get the call related details using Graph API: Reference doc => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way that you can handle the call triggered event at your custom application but you can get the call related details using Graph API: Reference doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

In order to get the Id which getting use to fetch `callRecords` you need to [Create subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example) to get call notifications.

> Create subscription- Subscribes a listener application to receive change notifications when the requested type of changes occur to the specified resource in Microsoft Graph.

[image]